# calling a unix exectuable via a java enterprise application

Tags: java

can a java application call a unix executable written in c++? basically i have written code in unix in c++ and shared the executable with a couple of companies. All is well save for this on e company that is using java under a linx platform. would it not be possible for them to just call my executable from their java app? of course i make sure my unix os matches their etc etc. but i don't want to redevelop my code using java for this. any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. To execute a command:

```
String command = "./myscript";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

You can change the command to execute your C++ program.

See also [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html) and [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) (the latter of which discusses Windows as well as *nix.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). I'm assuming your executable is a compiled command line application (and you're not out to call / integrate your C++ code from Java directly).

Answer (score 0):

Java would still be using the operating system to run the native code. To run your program on Linux you need to compile a Linux binary.

Comment: so i just need to recompile under linx which i intended to do anyway and then would they simply call it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes. What I think you're trying to do is use Java as a way to run a binary not intended for Linux. If this is the case, then Java won't help because Java will just use Linux to run that binary. You need to make a binary intended for Linux. They won't need Java to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Take a look at the [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class in the Java api, you will found your answer there. But also, be aware of what J2EE Specifications are about doing these kinds of things.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can run the command without Java, you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` to launch it from a Java process.